Why doesn’t Eloquent with() load related data when using join on a morphOne relationship?
I'm working with Laravel Eloquent and attempting to load related data using with() alongside a left join, but I'm running into issues. Specifically, I have a Company model with a morphOne relationship to a Featured model and a hasMany (or morphMany) relationship to Social models. Here are my relevant methods:
Github issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/53462
Company model:
public function featured(): MorphOne
{
    return $this->morphOne(Featured::class, 'featureable');
}

public function socials(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Social::class);
}

public function scopeJoinWithActiveFeatured(Builder $query): Builder
{
    return $query->leftJoin('featureds', function ($join) {
        $join->on('featureds.featureable_id', '=', 'companies.id')
             ->whereNotNull('featureds.featureable_id')
             ->whereDate('featureds.featured_from', '<=', now())
             ->whereDate('featureds.featured_until', '>=', now());
    });
}

In my query:
$companies = Company::query()
    ->when($request->filled('search'), fn($query) => $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('search') . '%'))
    ->JoinWithActiveFeatured()
    ->with(['socials'])
    ->orderBy('featureds.featureable_id', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('companies.name')
    ->paginate(6);

Problem:
When I include the JoinWithActiveFeatured scope, the socials relationship does not load, unless the company is featured (when scoped query matches). If I remove the join scope, socials loads correctly.
Why does join interfere with the with() loading of related data in this case and how can I load the socials relationship while also including a conditionally joined featured status??

I'm pretty sure that method names are case sensitive, so you need a lower case "j" like this: ->joinWithActiveFeatured().

Since you are using eloquent I don't see why you want to use a left join rather than another relationship with conditions.

If both tables have id then can you try exclude the features table from select part?
